# Error using tabstackengine package in latex

Tags: equations, align

I am trying to compile my document, however I am getting repeatedly error as follows:

```
Package listofitems Error: Empty list ignored, nothing to do. \end{align}
```

The line which corresponds to this error is:

```
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}^{n+1}=\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{c}\mathbf{\bar{Z}} \\ \hline \mathbf{0}\end{array}\right]}_{n}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2 \normalbaselineskip}
\vcenter{\hbox{\stackunder[0.1pt]{\left.{\Centerstack{}}\right\}\scriptstyle n}{\left.{\Centerstack{}}\right\}\scriptstyle m}}}
\end{align}
```

I don't know what is wrong in this. The output that is needed is as follows:

[image]

The same file was running perfectly fine in my other computer and that is why i uninstalled and re-installed latex, but this error keeps showing up.
 The preamble of my main file looks like this:

```
    \documentclass[twoside]{iitbreport}

%% Default spacing: 1.5
%% Default font size: 12pt
%% Default font: txfonts (similar to times new roman) 

%% Selectively comment out sections that you want to be left out but
%% maintaining the page numbers and other \ref
\includeonly{%
  intro/introduction_v2,
  lit/literature,
  chapter/chapter1v1,
  chapter/chapter2v1,
  chapter/chapter3v1,
  chapter/chapter4v1,
   chapter/conclusion,
  rnd/results, 
  dec,abs,pub,ack
}

%%% Some commonly used packages (make sure your LaTeX installation
%%% contains these packages, if not ask your senior to help installing
%%% the packages)

\usepackage{booktabs}
\graphicspath{{chapter/}}
\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use modern font encodings
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemist}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update} % only regenerate pdf files when eps file is newer
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{easybmat}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\allowdisplaybreaks

%%% Macro definitions for Commonly used symbols
\newcommand{\Rey}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{Re}}}
\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\ensuremath{\overline{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tenpow}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\ensuremath{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\numberwithin{lemma}{section}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\numberwithin{remark}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\numberwithin{proof}{section}
%\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\numberwithin{assumption}{section}
% Referencing macros
\newcommand{\Eqref}[1]{Equation~\eqref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Tabref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Appref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
```

The lines above the ones which corresponds to error are as below:

```
 \section{Householder Transformation for Square root filtering}
\label{ap:householder}
In this section we briefly discuss the Householder transformation technique to implement square root filtering in EGPOF (Section \ref{sc:online_algo_EGPOF}) for improved numerical precision. Detailed discussion for the same can be found in \cite{Maybeck}.

The a prior covariance matrix for EGPOF is $\mathbf{P}(k+1|k)$, and its square root is $\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)$ such that $\mathbf{P}(k+1|k)=\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)[\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)]^T$. The aposterior error covariance matrix is $\mathbf{P}(k+1|k+1)$, and its square root is $\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k+1)$. Also, square root of  $\left[\mathbf{\bar{Q}}-\mathbf{S}[\mathbf{R}]^{-1}[\mathbf{S}]^T\right]$ is given by $\mathbf{Q_{sq}}$ such that $\left[\mathbf{\bar{Q}}-\mathbf{S}[\mathbf{R}]^{-1}[\mathbf{S}]^T\right]=\mathbf{Q_{sq}}[\mathbf{Q_{sq}}]^T$. Then using Eq. \eqref{eq:pred_cov_lin}, the predicted covariance can be written as:
\begin{align}
\label{eq:pred_cov_household}
\mathbf{P}(k+1|k) &=\boldsymbol{\Phi}(k)\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k|k)[\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k|k)]^T\boldsymbol{\Phi}(k)^T+\boldsymbol{\Gamma}(k)\mathbf{Q_{sq}}[\mathbf{Q_{sq}}]^T[\boldsymbol{\Gamma}(k)]^T
\end{align}
Now it is desired to find the propagation equation for the square root of $\mathbf{P}(k+1|k)$; to find the relation to yield $\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)$ such that $\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)[\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)]^T$ is equal to the right hand side of Eq. \eqref{eq:pred_cov_household}. Suppose that we can find an orthogonal $(n+m)\times (n+m)$ matrix $\mathbf{\tilde{T}}$ i.e. $\mathbf{\tilde{T}}[\mathbf{\tilde{T}}]^T=\mathbf{I}$  such that
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{c:c}
\boldsymbol{\Phi}(k)\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k|k) & \boldsymbol{\Gamma}(k)\mathbf{Q_{sq}}
\end{array}\right]\mathbf{\tilde{T}}&=\left. \left[\begin{array}{c:c}\underbrace{\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)}_{\text{n columns}} & \underbrace{\mathbf{0}}_{\text{m columns}} \end{array}\right]\right\}\text{n rows} 
\end{align}
then in fact an $n \times n$ square root matrix $\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)$ will have been found which satisfies the desired relationship. Further, note that the same procedure could also be applied to:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}(k+1|k+1)=\big[\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{L}(k+1)\mathbf{C}(k+1)\big] \mathbf{P}(k+1|k) 
\big[\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{L}(k+1)\mathbf{C}(k+1)\big]^T + \mathbf{L}(k+1) \mathbf{R}  [\mathbf{L}(k+1)]^T
\end{align}
where, we find an orthogonal $(n+r)\times (n+r)$ matrix $\mathbf{\tilde{T}}$ i.e. $\mathbf{\tilde{T}}[\mathbf{\tilde{T}}]^T=\mathbf{I}$  such that
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{c:c}
\big[\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{L}(k+1)\mathbf{C}(k+1)\big]\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k) & \mathbf{L}(k+1) [\mathbf{R}]^{1/2}
\end{array}\right]\mathbf{\tilde{T}}&=\left. \left[\begin{array}{c:c}\underbrace{\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k+1)}_{\text{n columns}} & \underbrace{\mathbf{0}}_{\text{r columns}} \end{array}\right]\right\}\text{n rows} 
\end{align}
One of the method of generating such a $\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)$ and $\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k+1)$ is Householder transformation technique. Conceptually, it generated  $\mathbf{\tilde{T}}$ as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\tilde{T}}=\mathbf{\tilde{T}}^n\mathbf{\tilde{T}}^{(n-1)}\ldots \mathbf{\tilde{T}}^1
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{\tilde{T}}^k$ is generated recursively as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\tilde{T}}^k=\mathbf{I}-d^k\mathbf{u}^k[\mathbf{u}^k]^T
\end{align}
with the scalar $d^k$ and the $(n+m)$-vector $\mathbf{u}^k$ defined in the following. However, the computational algorithm never calculates these $\mathbf{\tilde{T}}^k$'s or $\mathbf{\tilde{T}}$ explicitly. The initial condition on the $(n+m)\times n$ $\mathbf{A}^k$ is 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}^1&=[\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)]^T=\left[\begin{array}{c:c}
\boldsymbol{\Phi}(k)\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k|k) & \boldsymbol{\Gamma}(k)\mathbf{Q_{sq}}
\end{array}\right]^T
\end{align}
Now letting $\mathbf{A}^k_j$ represent the $j^{th}$ column of $\mathbf{A}^k$, perform the $n$-step recursion, for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$:
\begin{align}
a^k &=\sqrt{\sum_{j=k}^{n+m}[A^k_{jk}]^2}\text{sign}\{A^k_{kk}\} \nonumber \\
d^k&=\frac{1}{a^k(a^k+A^k_{kk})} \nonumber \\
u_j^k&=\begin{cases}
0&  j< k\\
a^k+A^k_{kk}& j=k \\
A^k_{jk} & j=(k+1),\ldots ,(n+m)
\end{cases} \nonumber \\
y^k_j&=\begin{cases}
0 & j<k \\
1 & j=k \\
d^k[\mathbf{u}^{k}]^T\mathbf{A}^k_j & j=(k+1), \ldots , n
\end{cases} \nonumber\\
\mathbf{A}^{k+1}&=\mathbf{A}^k-\mathbf{u}^k [\mathbf{y}^{k}]^T
\label{eq:iter}
\end{align}
At stage $k$, the first $(k-1)$ columns of $\mathbf{A}^k$ are zero below the diagonal of the upper square partition, and $\mathbf{u}^k$ has been chosen so that the sub-diagonal elements of $\mathbf{A}^{k+1}_k$ will be zero. After the $n$ iterations of Eq. \eqref{eq:iter},
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}^{n+1}=\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{c}\mathbf{\bar{Z}} \\ \hline \mathbf{0}\end{array}\right]}_{n}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2 \normalbaselineskip}
\vcenter{\hbox{\stackunder[0.1pt]{\left.{\Centerstack{}}\right\}\scriptstyle n}{\left.{\Centerstack{}}\right\}\scriptstyle m}}}
\end{align} 
and then $\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)$ is generated as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P_{sq}}(k+1|k)=\left[\mathbf{\bar{Z}}\right]^T
\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcomer to TeX SX! Could you post  a smell, but complete, code reproducing the problem?

Comment: @Bernard: Thankyou for your comment. However the file is very big, and the error to which this line corresponds, I have posted that in question. I will add the preamble of my file for your reference

Comment: If you still have access to your earlier setup, or a log file from a successful run, compare that log file to the log from the failed run.  The important things to check are the version numbers of the packages, in particular the ones related to the stackengine.  Version incompatibility is the usual cause of such failures.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your comment. will surely check it.